# Duda con subselect con más de una columna

Tags: mysql

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

/* t) Listar los códigos de los empleados que tienen algún pedido 
con importe superior  a 10000 y que tengan  una  cuota  inferior
a 10000. */

Lo estoy intentando hacer con subselect aunque no tengo idea de si es posible, llevo hecho esto:

```sql
    select numemp, nombre
    from empleado
    where NumEmp in (select repclie
                     from cliente
                     where NUM_CLIE in (select cliente
                                        from pedido
                                        where numpedido in (select numpedido, sum(importe) total
                                                            from lineaspedido
                                                            group by 1
                                                            having total > 10000
                                                            ) 
                                        )
                     );
```

Me da el fallo `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Creo que tiene que ver con que en la última subselec estoy devolviendo dos columnas, pero no estoy seguro.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el ultimo subselect tenes que cambiar:

```
select numpedido, sum(importe) total
from lineaspedido
group by 1
having total > 10000
```

por:

```
select numpedido
from lineaspedido
group by numpedido
having sum(importe) > 10000
```

De cualquier forma no es comun tener que hacer tantos subqueries para obtener lo que necesitas, quizas si pasas las definiciones de tablas se puede rearmar en algo mas simple.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

¿Por definiciones de las tablas a qué terefieres?

¿Y cómo puedo pasarlas? Uso MySQL workbench por si afectara en algo.

Comment: cuales son los nombres de tablas y columnas que tiene, con sus tipos de datos y claves primarias y foraneas

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BlSVWi8Q6OBamn8zv8P8Jjwij-fIg8Lj/view?usp=sharing

Añado una imgen con el entidad relación, espero que os sirva. 

Thanks